# javascript algegra solve for x

Tags: javascript, algebra

I have the equation:

```
((fp*t)/acres)+rt=v
```

I know:

```
fp=.25
acres=40
rt=13
v=13.3
```

I need to solve for **t**

To do this on paper, I'd:
Simplify both sides of the equation.

```
0.00625t+13=13.3
```

Subtract 13 from both sides.

```
0.00625t+13−13=13.3−13

0.00625t=0.3
```

Divide both sides by 0.00625.

```
0.00625t/0.00625=0.3/0.00625
```

answer: t=48

How would I do that with javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change around your equation so `t` is alone:

```
var fp = .25;
var acres = 40;
var rt = 13;
var v = 13.3;

t = ((v - rt) * acres) / fp;

console.log(t); // ~48
```

Comment: `t` is still on both sides of the equation

Comment: No, it's not. `rt` is not `r * t`. (These variables are probably poorly named..)

Comment: No problem. It confused me at first glance also. Like I said, not great variable names. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```js
var fp = .25;
var acres = 40;
var rt = 13;
var v = 13.3;

t = ((v - rt) * acres) / fp;

alert(t);
```